# How do I make python randomly select something from a list and if typed in the input prompt, it will show the exact answer as intended

Tags: python, list, random, input, integer

Basically, I want to make a game something like among us, but different, just for fun
Anyways whenever I try to make it work, it will say my desired message no matter what.
Here's the code:

```
import turtle   
t=turtle.Turtle()  
import random       

imposteris = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'cyan', 'lime', 'black', 'white', 'purple', 'orange', 'brown']  
random.choice("imposteris")  
n = 1

print("Welcome to among them, you are a detective, figure out who the imposter is")   
meeting = int(input("Press 1 if you want to call a meeting"))   
if meeting:   
  input("A meeting has been called! Who do you think the imposter is?, Do either red, blue, green, cyan, lime, black, white, purple, orange, brown")   
  for i in range(n):   
    if random.choice(imposteris):   
      print("Congratulations, You caught the imposter.")      
    else:   
      print("He was a crewmate :/")
```

Comment: Can you reformat the code first？

Comment: Your code does not capture the value returned by functions.  For instance, you should have 1) `imposter = random.choice(imposteris)`, 2) `guess = input("A meeting has been called! Who do you think the imposter is?, Do either red, blue, green, cyan, lime, black, white, purple, orange, brown")`, 3) if `imposter == guess`:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do have to link a variable to your random choice, so in this case: `your_variable = random.choice(imposteris)`
then you can do whatever you want with the variable for example: `print(your_variable)`

Answer (score 2):

I took out your import of the Turtle module in order to test the code but you can put it back later.

````python
import random

imposters = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'cyan', 'lime', 'black', 'white', 'purple', 'orange', 'brown']

print("Welcome to among them, you are a detective, figure out who the imposter is\n")
print("Press 1 if you want to call a meeting")
meeting = int(input("> "))
if meeting:
    imposter = imposters[random.randint(0, len(imposters) - 1)]
    print(imposter)
    print("A meeting has been called! Who do you think the imposter is?, Do either red, blue, green, cyan, lime, black, white, purple, orange, brown")
    imposterGuess = str(input("> "))
if imposter == imposterGuess:
    print("Congratulations, You caught the imposter.")
else:
    print("%s was a crewmate :/" % imposterGuess)```
````

Comment: Wow everyone, thanks so much! This is really helpful to me